# Junit for controller is compiling but showing errors

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, springmockito

I am using an opensource project petclininc which follows Spring MVC pattern to write Junit test case using spring mocking service.

I started with a stand alone controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("visit")
public class VisitController {

    private final ClinicService clinicService;


    @Autowired
    public VisitController(ClinicService clinicService) {
        this.clinicService = clinicService;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/*/pets/{petId}/visits/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initNewVisitForm(@PathVariable("petId") int petId, Map<String, Object> model) {
        Pet pet = this.clinicService.findPetById(petId);
        Visit visit = new Visit();
        pet.addVisit(visit);
        model.put("visit", visit);
        return "pets/createOrUpdateVisitForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}/visits/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processNewVisitForm(@Valid Visit visit, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "pets/createOrUpdateVisitForm";
        } else {
            this.clinicService.saveVisit(visit);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/owners/{ownerId}";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/owners/*/pets/{petId}/visits", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showVisits(@PathVariable int petId) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("visitList");
        mav.addObject("visits", this.clinicService.findPetById(petId).getVisits());
        return mav;
    }

}
```

and my junit test case :

```
package org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.samples.petclinic.service.ClinicService;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("mvc-core-config.xml")

public class VisitControllerTest {


    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private ClinicService clinicService;

    @InjectMocks    
    private VisitController visitController;



    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new VetController(clinicService)).build();

    }


    @Test
    public void processNewVisitFormTest() throws Exception{



            this.mockMvc.perform(post("/owners/1/pets/1/visits/new"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(view()
                    .name("redirect:/owners/1"));
    }


}
```

When I am trying to run this test-case I get 
I changed it to spring/mvc-core-config.xml and the

```
fullstacktrace:INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/mvc-core-config.xml]
INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring/mvc-view-config.xml]
INFO  GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@276b998f: startup date [Fri Oct 10 13:42:21 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
ERROR TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@28a6683d] to prepare test instance [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web.VisitControllerTest@450591a4]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) ~[junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) ~[junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) ~[junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) ~[junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) ~[junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) ~[junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) ~[.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) ~[.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in class path resource [spring/mvc-core-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web.PetTypeFormatter#7f95a585' of type [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web.PetTypeFormatter] while setting bean property 'formatters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web.PetTypeFormatter#7f95a585' defined in class path resource [spring/mvc-core-config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.service.ClinicService]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.service.ClinicService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.service.ClinicService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedSet(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:371) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:744) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:250) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.samples.petclinic.web.PetTypeFormatter#7f95a585' defined in class path resource [spring/mvc-core-config.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.service.ClinicService]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.service.ClinicService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.service.ClinicService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.samples.petclinic.service.ClinicService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Comment: How is * treated in `@RequestMapping` ?

Comment: The title is misleading. It does compile but it does not work.

Comment: Show the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly at the end the line of the stacktrace `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [mvc-core-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist at ..` says, that spring cannot find your config file. 
Is your spring-configuration located under "src/main/resources/" or "src/test/resources" (if you use maven) ? Then try to configure your test with this: `@ContextConfiguration("classpath:mvc-core-config.xml")`

Comment: I already tried with that and it is not working as well./spring-petclinic/src/main/resources/spring/mvc-core-config.xml is the actual path of mvc-core-config.xml. Am I doing the mocking in the right way?

Comment: I changed it to spring/mvc-core-config.xml and the fullstacktrace:

Comment: if you edit the original post, please mention it next time. i was wondering about your stacktrace.
it looks like the clinicService cannot be found as a dependency. you have to define it in your mvc config or import the service-config as well.